# Instagram lookup user

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I tried the following endpoint:

```
GET https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?access_token=<token>&q=emilia_clarke
```

but what I got was :

```
{"meta": {"code": 200}, "data": []}
```

the token has public scope. what did I miss? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Sandbox mode, you can only search on sandbox users. To search among all users, you should go live.

Edit your clients and invite a few users into your sandbox. And then you give it a try.

Sandbox mode is the first status of any Instagram apps. Until you go live, you will encounter some limitations.  More Information about Sandbox
https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

Comment: I can search all sandbox users, or just sandbox user registered to my app?

Comment: Just sandbox user registered to your app.

Answer (score 0):

The `/users/search` endpoint searches users *by name*. I guess that `emilia_clarke` is not the name (it's probably `Emilia Clarke`) but the ID. In this case when you know the ID already, you need the `/users/{user-id}` endpoint, e.g. `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/emilia_clarke/?access_token=<token>`